# Can your embeded code on other sites increase seo rank?

Tags: seo

I'm working on a video hosting website and I'm wondering how my embeded code would affect ny seo rank

for example:
`<iframe width="420" height="315" src="//www.mywebsite.com/embed/Bp222aodrVg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

Can your embeded code on other sites improve of hurt your seo rank?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: @JohnConde so for what do you have seo tag here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can improve your ranking.
This works good for sites that have a high Google Page Rank - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank.

A lot of links from low ranked sites won't help you much.

What you want to get is backlinks from high quality sides, called backlinks - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backlink. Yes, even links to images/videos on your side can increase your Google ranking.